# Выделить текст в HTML

Tags: html, css

Есть тег (в Python шаблоне) `<p>{{ event.date }} {{ event.name }}</p>`. Мне нужно выделить текст `{{ event.date }}` серым, как это сделать ?

Comment: Изучить основы HTML и CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Приветствую!

```
<p style="color: gray;">{{ event.date }} {{ event.name }}</p>
```

**UPD**

```
<p>{{ event.date }} <span style="color: gray;">{{ event.name }}</span></p>
```

Comment: Нет, тогда у меня и `{{event.name }}` станет серым, а надо чтоб только `{{event.date}}`

Comment: @Антон Оберните `{{event.date}}` в тэг `<span>` и для span присвойте стиль

Comment: @Антон ну это уже сами решайте :) А в целом, выделите день и изучите основы HTML\CSS как посоветовал: **andreymal**